# Forcing C standard in CMake

Tags: c, cmake, c99, c11

I am trying to use C11 instead of C99 in my CMake project.

I tried setting the standard like this:

```
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
```

And like this as well:

```
set_property(TARGET vkvoxel PROPERTY C_STANDARD 11)
```

But none of them didn't work.
So I tried forcing them:

```
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)
```

And like this:

```
set_property(TARGET vkvoxel PROPERTY C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

But I still would get:

```
C:\Users\REDACTED\Documents\vkvoxel\source\voxel.c:13:22: error: call to undeclared library function 'aligned_alloc' with type 'void *(unsigned long long, unsigned long long)'; ISO C99 and later do
      not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   13 |         chunkbuffer->data = aligned_alloc(16, sizeof(chunk_t) * size);
```

I did in fact have `stdlib.h` included, but it indicates that I'm still using C99, even though I forced C11 in the CMake configuration...
Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: What did the compiler command line contain — the one that produced the error message?

Comment: *"But none of them didn't work."* How did you determine that it didn't work? *"but it indicates that I'm still using C99, even though I forced C11"* Error message you posted says "ISO C99 **and later**". In order to know if you are compiling with C11, you need to look at actual command line parameters that are given to the compiler.